Скрипт roblox studio
Итак, у меня не обновляется счётчик. Есть глобальная переменная ScorePaint. Она должна показываться в TextLabel есть скрипт на измену пустой строки на ScorePaint. Он не работает. Вот он:
local TextLabel = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel
while true do
    TextLabel.Text = tostring(_G.ScorePaint)
    print(1)
    wait(0.5)
    if _G.ScorePaint == 6 then
        break
    end
end


зачем через _G вводить? устаревшая дичь уже

проверь изменяется ли вообще ScorePaint где то в других скриптах

У меня пустая строка, при входе она изменяется на 0.
